# wkhtmltopdf and CSS variables

Tags: css, pdf

I'm using *wkhtmltopdf* 0.12.6 to generate PDFs from HTML.

But even that version pretty recent doesn't seem to support CSS variables.

```
.pdf { color:#123; }
```

works, but

```
:root { --mycolor:#123; }
...
.pdf { color:var(--mycolor); }
```

doesn't (rule ignored).

CSS variables are common nowadays, so there must be an option or a trick to get them understood by wkhtmltopdf?

Does anyone has some clue?

(tried changing the declaration location, names, ... to no avail).

Comment: Maybe wkhtmltopdf's version is pretty recent, but is webkits?

Comment: This  could be the issue, the wk folks still using an old webkit(?) Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Maybe check out full-fledged browser automation frameworks (Playwright, Selenium, …). They require you to write code but they use up-to-date browsers.

Comment: @Déjàvu Try https://github.com/Sicos1977/ChromeHtmlToPdf or https://github.com/dataverity/chromehtml2pdf